# How do I make a div the size of its parent div

Tags: html, css, swipe

Hello I am making a picture slider (like Netflix) by using swiperjs. But I have issues with my next and prev buttons. With the CSS I have, the buttons take 100% height of the whole screen and don't stick next to the slider.

```css
.thumbTiles .swiper-button-prev,
.thumbTiles .swiper-button-next {
  height: 100%;
  width: 4%;
  width: calc(4% - 5px);
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: rgba(20, 20, 20, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<section class="thumbSection">
  <h2 class="thumbTitle">Popular Now</h2>
  <div class="thumbTiles swiper-container">

    <!-- Navigation buttons -->
    <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
    <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
    <!-- Wrapper -->

    <div class="swiper-wrapper">

      <!-- Slides -->
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <a class="thumbTile" href="#">
          <img class="thumbTile__image" src="https://imagelink" alt="The Queen's Gambit">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <a class="thumbTile" href="#">
                            <img class="thumbTile__image"
                                src="https://imagelink
                                alt="Dark">
                        </a>
      </div>
```

With this code the navigation buttons appear like this (I don't know if it's clear on the image but the Next & Prev Buttons taking 100% height of the page.
[Next & Prev Buttons taking 100% height of the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NUVq2.png)

Do you know how can I make them stick next to the slider and 100% height of their parent Div (like on the Netflix web page) instead of the whole screen ?

I used the code from this guy's link (https://jsfiddle.net/iamstratos/oudachrn/1/) but when I tested it he have the same issue as me.

Thank you for the help :)

Comment: There is a syntax error in your HTML...

Comment: I migrated your code to a snippet, please edit it to reproduce your problem.